# jQuery 1.5: Why is Deferred object calling .done() in UNRESOLVED state?

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.5, jquery-deferred

I've created a test page that mimics the problem I am getting on my actual page.

As you can see in `doSomething2()`, the dfd object is deliberately never resolved. However, when I run the following code, the `.done()` in `doSomething()` always fires. Inspecting the console, you will see that `dfd.isResolved()` is *false* right before `.done()` runs.

Any insights? Any help is appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
    <title>Testing Page</title>
    <script src="jquery-git-02092011.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">
            <div ></div>
            <div ></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function doSomething() {
            $('#test div').each(function(){
                $(this).append($('<div></div>').load('http://www.google.com',function(){
                    doSomething2().done(console.log('dosomething2 is complete'));   
                }))
            });
        }

        function doSomething2() {
            var dfd = $.Deferred();
            console.log(dfd.isResolved());
            return dfd;
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
          doSomething();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

edit: 
I UNDERSTAND that this function accomplishes nothing. I've just made an example to replicate my problem.
I UNDERSTAND that fetching 'google.com' is against SOP. I've just created this example to replicate my problem. I am developing a web app that is meant to run locally from one html file. In this case, SOP is not strictly adhered to, so this should be ok to at least test.

**edit:I've created a jsfiddle to test this behavior:** http://jsfiddle.net/Sgwpv/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this passing in a statement to .done rather then a function

see live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/TsYcz/1/)

Internally, `.done` takes a list of functions and pushes them to a callback array so

`callbacks.push(elem);`

You pass in a statement as `elem` and get

`callbacks.push(alert("foo"));`

Your pushing the return value of the statement (in this case `undefined`) to the callback array rather then a function.